# android - connect to server screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that on startup it communicates with my server and gets some data.

I want to add some "wait window" to the homapage of the app that indicate that such communication is taking place. I want that window to pop up and the rest of the home page will be faded in the background.

In case of success fetching the data this window will disappear and from there it will be normal use. If there was an error, or a connection with the server can not be established I want to give 2 options: Retry or close app.

My main challenge is the that window popping and make the homepage to be faded in the background. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: how I make such window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up a progress dialog during the execution of AsyncTask where it fetches data from your server and dismiss the dialog after fetching all the data.

Your code might be something like this.

```
class LoadFeed extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    private Dialog progressDialog;
    Context context;

    public LoadFeed(Context context){
        progressDialog = getProgressDialog(context, "Updating Items", "Fetching updates...");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //fetching of data

        return null;

    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

public Dialog getProgressDialog(Context context, String title, String msg){

     ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
     dialog.setTitle(title);
     dialog.setMessage(msg);
     dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
     dialog.setCancelable(true);

     return dialog;
}
```

Comment: "SystemHelper cannot be resolved". I can't import it either. what is it?

Comment: Thanks. I just can't pass the right context because I am getting `ndroid.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application` I got it when I tried `MyActivity.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: ok That's good. If this helps or answered your problem it would be good to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: I will don't worry :) just help me please with the context parameter please

Comment: I thought you already got it? BTW where did you placed the code?

Comment: I have AsyncTask that fetch the data from the server. I added your suggestion to its code. I call it like that: `AccessWebServiceTask task = new AccessWebServiceTask(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
task.execute();` but as I said on runtime I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: Don't use this `MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()` you are using the context of the application use the context of the activity. Try using `this` only.